Can curvature be used at centripetal acceleration and force?
when I say curvature I mean it as the definition of mathematics $$k=\left|\left|\frac{d\mathbf{T}}{ds}\right|\right|$$so not relativity or anything of that sort, this is purely classical physics.
So, now to the main point, I remembered today some stuff from when I had physics classes, and I ended up thinking about centripetal force and acceleration. I have a problem, if I don't have a circle, how am I supposed to get centripetal acceleration if $a_c={v^2\over r}$, but then I remembered that curvature has a very nice property where $k={1\over r}$, r being the radius of the osculating circle which is the circle that approximates the best at a point of a curve.
so my question is if $a_c=kv^2$ holds true?

This is a valid question in my opinion - you might want to make a newline in the paragraph to separate the "here's my question" part from the rest of it so it's clearer at first glance what your question is. Also, the answer to your question would be yes, since $a_c=v^2/r=kv^2$ by definition.

Im not sure about the mathematics classes you've taken but in learning vector calculus, these terms were immediately likened to their kinematics counterparts in my classes. In fact the book I used literally introduced the Frenet-Serret formulas.

Triatticus, I know what you're talking about, but the main focus is the the equations of the modulus of centripetal acceleration and force, my point and question is if $kv^2=\frac{v^2}{r}$, there's some context where this change would be useful for example it's easier to talk about curvature to determine the maximum velocity a train would go along a train track than it would be with a radius, hope this cleared things up :)
